# File not found with file result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an action that serves the file:

```
public ActionResult() GetFile
{
     return this.File("C:\\test.txt", "text/plain",
                "test.txt");
}
```

But action causes an error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not find file: C:\test.txt
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.VirtualFileResultExecutor+d__4.MoveNext()

I am sure that file exstis - it can be opened via "Run" window (Win + R).
Why Asp.net core mvc doesn't "see" the file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `File()` overload that accepts a `string`, is defined as:

```
public virtual VirtualFileResult File(string virtualPath, string contentType)
```

As you can see, the name of the parameter is `virtualPath`. That means you have to pass a *virtual* path to the file, not a physical path.

(Virtual path means a path that is relative to the current application. For example: `~/Content/test.txt`, where `~` denotes the application root directory.)

If you're insisting on serving a physical file that is above your application root, you can read it beforehand and pass the actual bytes to the corresponding `File()` overload:

```
var physicalFilePath = "C:\\test.txt";
var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(physicalFilePath);

return this.File(fileBytes, "text/plain", "test.txt");
```

**Update:**

Actually, the base controller *does* provide a `PhysicalFile()` method that can be used to serve a file using a physical path. In your case:

```
return PhysicalFile("C:\\test.txt", "text/plain", "test.txt");
```

You should also keep in mind that (usually) the process under which your application runs, won't have suffice permissions to read from the root of `C:\`.

See [Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c2fee4d74d642ade9cf513fc60498aafcb51f9c0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ControllerBase.cs#L726)

Comment: Thanks - PhysicalFile is what I was looking for. Anyway - strange exception. More meaning-full message (f.e. given path is not virtual)) could be helpful :)

Comment: Very well explained. I was also wondering why it was not working with return File(...). Thank you.